# Need help for inserting values in between each value of a list

Tags: python, list, append

I am having a list `column_names` with below values

```
 column_names = ['Large Cap', 'Mid Cap', 'Small Cap', 'Value']
```

I need to create a list with below output. Duplicate values and append strings alternatively(_PE & _book) to values in list.
Expected output:

```
column_names_PE =  ['Large Cap_PE', 'Large Cap_book','Mid Cap_PE','Mid Cap_book' 'Small Cap_PE', 'Small Cap_book' 'Value_PE','Value_book']
```

I can append strings using code `[s + "_PE" for s in column_names]`. But not sure how to duplicate and append strings alternatively. Can any one please help me.

Comment: In python it is just a list, unlike java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have:

```
column_names = ['Large Cap', 'Mid Cap', 'Small Cap', 'Value']
suffixes = ["_PE", "_book"]
```

To create the list with suffixes, you can do:

**Using a classic loop:**

```
column_names_PE = []
for column_name in column_names:
    for suffix in suffixes:
        column_names_PE.append(column_name + suffix)
```

**Using a list in comprehension:**

```
column_names_PE = [column_name + suffix
                   for column_name in column_names
                   for suffix in suffixes]
```

**You get:**

```
['Large Cap_PE',
 'Large Cap_book',
 'Mid Cap_PE',
 'Mid Cap_book',
 'Small Cap_PE',
 'Small Cap_book',
 'Value_PE',
 'Value_book']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just iterate through `column_names` and append a value for `item + "_PE"` and `item + "_book"`:

```
column_names = ['Large Cap', 'Mid Cap', 'Small Cap', 'Value']

column_names_PE = []

for item in column_names:
  column_names_PE.append(item + "_PE")
  column_names_PE.append(item + "_book")

print(column_names_PE)
# ['Large Cap_PE', 'Large Cap_book', 'Mid Cap_PE', 'Mid Cap_book',
#  'Small Cap_PE', 'Small Cap_book', 'Value_PE', 'Value_book']
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple list-comprehension would get you a bit closer:

```
>>> [[c + '_PE', c + '_book'] for c in column_names]
[['Large Cap_PE', 'Large Cap_book'], ['Mid Cap_PE', 'Mid Cap_book'], ['Small Cap_PE', 'Small Cap_book'], ['Value_PE', 'Value_book']]
```

To flatten the nested list, you could use `chain` from `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([[c + '_PE', c + '_book'] for c in column_names]))
['Large Cap_PE', 'Large Cap_book', 'Mid Cap_PE', 'Mid Cap_book', 'Small Cap_PE', 'Small Cap_book', 'Value_PE', 'Value_book']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[item for sublist in [(s + "_PE",s + "_book") for s in column_names] for item in sublist]
```

You could try this list comprehension which appends a tuple and then flattens the list. Result:

```
['Large Cap_PE',
 'Large Cap_book',
 'Mid Cap_PE',
 'Mid Cap_book',
 'Small Cap_PE',
 'Small Cap_book',
 'Value_PE',
 'Value_book']
```